# Laravel multiple Page

Tags: laravel-8

I will write a project with Laravel, but I would like to share with you an issue that is on my mind.

There are 4 languages ​​in the Language Table,

There will be more than one record in the pages table
Example;
*about us
*über uns
*à propos de nous
*om oss
These four pages represent the About Us Page

How can I link these four pages together?

After all my research, I haven't come across anything like this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read these in order :

1. [Laravel doc localization](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization)
2. [Beginners guide setting up multi language support in laravel](https://arjunamrutiya.medium.com/beginners-guide-setting-up-multi-language-support-in-laravel-59fe6d88d0ad)
3. [Design a translatable database](https://medium.com/@styles77/working-with-multi-languages-in-laravel-without-packages-b4dc8bfa9ab8)

---

structure lang directory :

```
├── lang/       
│   ├── en/
│   │   ├── paths.php
│   ├── fr/
│   │   ├── paths.php
│   ├── jp/
│   │   ├── paths.php
│   ├── pt/
│   │   ├── paths.php
```

create languages.php in config folder :

```
<?php 
    return [
    'en',
    'pt',
    'fr',
    'jp'
];
```

create middleware in handle method setting locale :

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    $lang = $request->segment(1);
    
    if(strlen($lang) === 2 && in_array($lang,config('languages'))){
        app()->setLocale($lang);
    }
    
    return $next($request);
}
```

in routing :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'set-locale'], function() {
    foreach (config('languages') as $locale) {
        if (config('app')['locale'] == $locale) {
            Route::get(__('paths.about', [], $locale), [AboutController::class, 'index'])->name("about.{$locale}");
        } else {
            Route::get("{$locale}/".__('paths.about', [], $locale), [AboutController::class, 'index'])->name("about.{$locale}");
        }
    }
});
```